# Почему jQuery при переключении шагает на +1 кнопку?

Tags: html, jquery

Есть реализация смены табов, выглядит так:
jQuery:

```js
$('.wrapper-content').each(function() {
  let temp = $(this);
  temp.find('.buy__product').not(':first').hide();
  temp.find('.button-item').click(function() {
    temp.find('.button-item').removeClass('active').eq($(this).index()).addClass('active');
    temp.find('.buy__product').hide().eq($(this).index()).fadeIn()
  }).eq(0).addClass('active');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-id="standart" class="wrapper-content tabs__content item active">
  <div class="left-side">
    <p class="title__pag">Базовые параметры:</p>
    <div class="stock-params">
      <div class="item-params">
        <p class="title">Ширина:</p>
        <p class="desc">3м</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item-params">
        <p class="title">Высота:</p>
        <p class="desc">2,1м</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item-params">
        <p class="title">Каркас:</p>
        <p class="desc">Оцинкованная труба 20х40 мм, цельные оцинкованные дуги</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item-params">
        <p class="title">Комплектность:</p>
        <p class="desc">2 двери, 2 форточки, надежное болтовое крепление</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item-params">
        <p class="title">Прочность:</p>
        <p class="desc">Не требует ухода и подпорок на Зиму</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-side">
    <p class="title__pag">Комплектация:</p>
    <div class="edit-params">
      <div class="item-params">
        <p class="title">Длина:</p>
        <button class="button button-item">[[1000]]</button>
        <button class="button button-item">[[2000]]</button>
      </div>
      <div class="item-params">
        <p class="title">Шаг между дугами:</p>
        <button class="button active">1м</button>
      </div>
      <div class="item-params">
        <p class="title">Боковые усиления:</p>
        <button class="button active">5 штук</button>
      </div>
      <div class="item-params">
        <p class="title">Поликарбонат:</p>
        <button class="button active">Пластилюкс стандарт 4мм</button>
      </div>
      <div class="item-params">
        <p class="title">Фундамент:</p>
        <button class="button active">Т-образные ножки</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="buy__product">
    <a href="#!" class="buy__src">
      <p class="buy_desc">Оформить заказ</p>
      <div class="buy_price">
        <p class="price">
          1000
          <span class="price-currency">&#8381;</span></p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="buy__product">
    <a href="#!" class="buy__src">
      <p class="buy_desc">Оформить заказ</p>
      <div class="buy_price">
        <p class="price">
          2000
          <span class="price-currency">&#8381;</span></p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Сама смена работает, но когда я нажимаю на первую кнопку, нажимается вторая. А при нажатии на вторую, всё ломается, будто скрипт пытается сработать на 3 кнопку, но её нет.

Comment: Добавьте пример кода который можно запустить - будет намного проще подсказать :)

Comment: Правил, посмотрите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.wrapper-content').each(function() {
  let temp = $(this);
  temp.find('.buy__product').not(':first').hide();
  temp.find('.button-item').click(function() {
    temp.find('.button-item').removeClass('active').eq($(this).index()).addClass('active');
    temp.find('.buy__product').hide().eq($(this).index()).fadeIn()
  }).eq(0).addClass('active');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-id="standart" class="wrapper-content tabs__content item active">
  <div class="left-side">
    <p class="title__pag">Базовые параметры:</p>
    <div class="stock-params">
      <div class="item-params">
        <p class="title">Ширина:</p>
        <p class="desc">3м</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item-params">
        <p class="title">Высота:</p>
        <p class="desc">2,1м</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item-params">
        <p class="title">Каркас:</p>
        <p class="desc">Оцинкованная труба 20х40 мм, цельные оцинкованные дуги</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item-params">
        <p class="title">Комплектность:</p>
        <p class="desc">2 двери, 2 форточки, надежное болтовое крепление</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item-params">
        <p class="title">Прочность:</p>
        <p class="desc">Не требует ухода и подпорок на Зиму</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-side">
    <p class="title__pag">Комплектация:</p>
    <div class="edit-params">
      <div class="item-params">
        <p class="title">Длина:</p>
        <div>
          <button class="button button-item">[[1000]]</button>
          <button class="button button-item">[[2000]]</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item-params">
        <p class="title">Шаг между дугами:</p>
        <button class="button active">1м</button>
      </div>
      <div class="item-params">
        <p class="title">Боковые усиления:</p>
        <button class="button active">5 штук</button>
      </div>
      <div class="item-params">
        <p class="title">Поликарбонат:</p>
        <button class="button active">Пластилюкс стандарт 4мм</button>
      </div>
      <div class="item-params">
        <p class="title">Фундамент:</p>
        <button class="button active">Т-образные ножки</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="buy__product">
    <a href="#!" class="buy__src">
      <p class="buy_desc">Оформить заказ</p>
      <div class="buy_price">
        <p class="price">
          1000
          <span class="price-currency">&#8381;</span></p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="buy__product">
    <a href="#!" class="buy__src">
      <p class="buy_desc">Оформить заказ</p>
      <div class="buy_price">
        <p class="price">
          2000
          <span class="price-currency">&#8381;</span></p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как оказалось `eq($(this).index())` возвращает значения с первого элемента внутри контейнера, даже если у него нет класса `button-item`, т.е. по сути брал своего соседа слева, в моём случае это `Длина:

. Решением было просто взять кнопки в дополнительный блок:

```
<div class="item-params">
   <p class="title">Длина:</p>
   <div>
   <button class="button button-item">[[1000]]</button>
   <button class="button button-item">[[2000]]</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...eq($(this).index())
              ^^^^^ - это возвращает не то, что Вы думаете
```

https://api.jquery.com/index/

```
temp.find('.button-item').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).index());
  console.log(temp.find('.button-item').index(this));
  ...
```